# Regex expression partly validating expression

Tags: java, regex, validation

I am  currently building web application in Java and I am new to regex.I have the following requirements to validate a formula:

A formula can contain the following set of characters:

- Digit: 0 - 9
- Alpha: A - Z
- Operators: *, /, +, -
- Separator: ;

Condition:

- Formula must start with “T”
- The character “T” must always be followed by a digit or an alpha.
- The separator must always be followed by “T”.
- The character “M” must always be followed by an operator.
- An operator must always be followed by a digit

I have the following  expression as shown below:

```
^(?!.*[*+/-]\D)(?!.*T\W)(?!.*[;:][^T])(?!.*M[^*+/-])[T][A-Z0-9 +/*;:-]*$
```

The following expression is being met with the above regex expression which is valid:

TA123;T1*2/32M+

But I don't know how to add the following validation to the regex expression above:

- An operator must always be followed by a digit
- The character “T” must always be followed by a digit or an alpha.
- The separator must always be followed by “T”
- The character “M” must always be followed by an operator.

The regex expression above valid the above condition partly only those one below should be invalid but it is valid which is wrong:

The one below should not work as  an operator(*, /, +, -) must always be followed by a digit but in this case it is valid:

```
T4R*
```

The one below should not work as character “T” must always be followed by a digit or an alpha but in this case it is valid:

```
T4RT
```

The one below should not work as a separator(;) must always be followed by “T” but in this case it is valid:

```
T4;
```

The one below should not work as character “M” must always be followed by an operator but in this case it is valid:

```
T4RTM
```

Hi @vks,

After applying your changes to the reg expression pls find result below:

The one below should not work as an operator(*, /, +, -) must always be followed by a digit

It works with character but not with digit and the expected one is digit:

Invalid T4R*H

valid T4R*5

The character “T” must always be followed by a digit or an alpha:

T4RT   invalid as expected
T4RT5  should be valid but the actual result is invalid
T4R    should be valid but actual result invalid

The separator(;) must always be followed by “T”:

T4;T   should be valid but the actual result is invalid
 T4;    invalid as expected

The character “M” must always be followed by an operator:

T4RTM+ should be valid but actual result invalid
  T4RTM  invalid as expected

Any idea how what changes needed to the regex expression in order to fullfil the above criteria pls?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: `TA123;T1*2/32M+` is invalid too as there is no digit ahead of it.Please add some valid exmaples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex is correct.The only way it can fail is if you have a `newline` after you input.To solve that you can use

```
^(?!.*[TM*+/;:-]$)(?!.*[*+/-]\D)(?!.*T\W)(?!.*[;:][^T])(?!.*M[^*+/-])[T][A-Z0-9 +/*;:-]*$
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sS2dM8/51

Comment: hi thanks for the reply question updated according to the new expresion

Comment: @user1999453 T4RTM+ cannot be valid as there is no digit after operator.check edit!!!!!!!!!

Comment: apologies my mistake for T4RTM+, it works fine now thanks a lot vks.

Answer (score -1):

Break the task down into smaller pieces, and solve them **one by one**.

The solution could look like this:

- check `/^[0-9A-Z\*\/\+\-\;]*$/` https://regex101.com/r/sS2dM8/46
- check `/^T.*$/` (Formula must start with “T”) https://regex101.com/r/sS2dM8/45
- check that `/^.*T(?![0-9A-Z]).*$/` does not match (it would match, if there was a `T` not followed by a digit or alpha) https://regex101.com/r/sS2dM8/47
- check that `/^.*;(?!T).*$/` does not match (it would match, if there was a separator not followed by a `T`) https://regex101.com/r/sS2dM8/48
- check that `/^.*M(?![\*\/\+\-]).*$/` does not match (it would match, if there was a `M` not followed by an operator) https://regex101.com/r/sS2dM8/49
- check that `/^.*[\*\/\+\-](?!\d).*$/` does not match (it would match, if there was an operator not followed by a digit) https://regex101.com/r/sS2dM8/50
- you can easily check further things here

Downsides:

1. slightly worse performance

Upsides:

1. easier to read and understand
2. easier to maintain and expand
3. easier to test